# Flutter Draggable widget that can be clicked or dragged to move to DragTarget

Tags: flutter, dart, draggable, clickable

I am trying to create a small test that allows a user to click or drag a Draggable or Container to move it to a DragTarget. The best example I can think of for this would be how Duolingo allows for their users to click a word and automatically move it to the first location of a sentence to a certain target, then the app checks if the sequence is correct.

For those who are unfamiliar with how Duolingo uses this, I'll explain what I would like to do here.  I would like to have 3 Draggables (call them A, B, and C), and 3 DragTargets. When a letter is clicked it will move to the leftmost empty DragTarget, however, the letter could also be dragged to the location as well. If a Draggable is clicked while inside the DragTarget it will return to its original location, or it could be dragged to switch spots with another filled DragTarget.

I hope that explained my goal well. If not please ask for more details and I can try to edit and provide them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem when detecting a click event on a Draggable while still providing the rest of the drag functionality. I found a workaround by checking the `DragDetails.velocity` on the end of the drag and maintaining a state variable to check if the element was dragged.

Code Example:

```
onDragStarted: () {
  controller.wasCardDragged = false;
},
onDragEnd: (details) {
  if (details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx == 0
      && details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dy == 0 
      && !controller.wasCardDragged) {
  // click event happened
  // add your click event here
}
                  },
onDragUpdate: (details) {
  controller.wasCardDragged = true;
},
```

When the velocity is 0 when `onDragEnd` is called and `onDragUpdate` was not triggered during the drag, this is basically equivalent to a click event.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

What could work is to use the `onDragStarted: () {}` voidCallback which will be similar to a button click. You could use A `Stack()` and wrap the Draggables with an `AnimatedPositioned()` widget. To which field to move can propably be determined using If statements.

Comment: But how would you determine if the user had dragged it or clicked it? You can't just take action on drag start for a click since the user may drag it.